# Validate data given a LDM from PowerDesigner

Tags: powerdesigner

I am completely new to PowerDesigner, so please bear with me if I sound naive.

For a project we're working on, there's an external specification published in the form of Logical Data Model (LDM), developed using PowerDesigner. Our team is supposed to validate a dataset (available as a bunch of CSV files) against this data model. This validation should include the basic technical validations like the data types, availability of mandatory attributes and the business rules specified in the LDM.

How does one go about with the validation? Google search could not find any straight answers. I came up with this:

1) It is possible to easily convert the Logical Data Model into MS SQL Server physical model

2) Create empty tables with the required constraints.

3) Validate each record against this SQL schema (using SQL Server SSIS?)

Is this the most efficient way? Any better alternative to MS SQL Server, to stay in the SAP world, close to PowerDesigner.

Thanks.​

Comment: Good idea. In which language are the business rules specified?

Comment: You can probably use any database with a mean to import CSV. e.g. MySQL.